# How to populate array in Rails view using Slim syntax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, slim-lang

I'm using slim with a small array to populate a select tag.

first attempt:

```
=f.select (:productline) do
    -[["productlinetest","value"],["[B] Bolted Bonnet"] ].each do |c|
        = content_tag(:option, c.first, value: c.last)
```

This works fine but if i want to add more options I would have to have them all on the same line. I would prefer something like this:

```
=f.select (:productline) do
    -[
        ["productlinetest","value"],
        ["[B] Bolted Bonnet"]
        ].each do |c|
        = content_tag(:option, c.first, value: c.last)
```

but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move your array into the controller action, and use `@variable` in views:

```
def my_awesome_action
   @array = [["productlinetest","value"],
             ["[B] Bolted Bonnet"]]
end
```

in views:

```
= f.select (:productline) do
    - @array.each do |c|
        = content_tag(:option, c.first, value: c.last)
```

`Slim` template engine doesn't allow multi line expression like in `Ruby`

Comment: Is there any way to do this in the view?  I wouldn't have a problem doing it through the controller but there are a lot of specialized forms involved.

Comment: @suavocado do it in views, a bad practice.

Comment: Okay, i'll make it work.  Thanks for answering so quickly

Comment: I have to wait 2 more minutes